What's "pick up" mean in "if you'd picked up with one of them"?
This context comes from a movie "Before Sunrise" 1995. It's a scene in which a young American man who is a passenger on a train meets a young French girl. He starts talking to her and as they start to hit it off he tries to convince her to get off before her in Vienna in order to spend a night ther together.

Alright, alright. Think of it like this: jump ahead, ten, twenty years, okay, and you're married. Only your marriage doesn't have that same energy that it used to have, y'know. You start to blame your husband. You start to think about all those guys you've met in your life and what might have happened if you'd picked up with one of them, right? Well, I'm one of those guys.

​(informal) to start again; to continue
Let's pick up where we left off yesterday.(Oxford Leaners Dictionary)
Does this sentence mean that she would be thinking "about all those guys she's met in her life and what might have happened if she "renewed the relationship with on of them?"

Hm, it doesn't seem to really align to a standard usage that I'm aware of. But the meaning is so clear that it's hard to notice. Clearly, from context, it means "if you had [in a hypothetical past] wound up in a relationship with one of them (instead of your also-hypothetical husband)."

What's funny is that no young French girl would really get that. pick up with here means to start a relationship with.

@Lambie Unless the person you're talking to is visibly struggling to understand a foreign language, I don't think people tailor their speaking away from their normal vernacular. Most of my coworkers are European, I use lots of American idioms with them.

@Lambie That's my point: people talking to foreigners who seem fluent don't know what they will or won't understand, so they talk normally. I haven't seen the movie, did the character understand?

Also, people can often pick up what's meant from the context. He could have put almost any verb there and the intent would be clear.

@Barmar That's what makes it funny. Usually, someone who is used to talking to persons with another native tongue can gauge their level pretty quickly. Maybe the authors did this on purpose. But very often they don't.

Whick kind of makes this question funny. It seems obvious what he's talking about, even if it doesn't correspond to the dictionary definition. But maybe someone who isn't a native speaker is always unsure of their interpretation of strange phrases.

I probably shouldn't respond to trolling/irrelevant debates here, but the French verb lever means essentially the same as "pick up" both in the sense of lift and to talk to a member of the opposite/appropriate sex with a view to sleeping with them. So it's likely a French person would work that out.

@StuartF - mais je drague les filles, moi !

"Well, I'm one of those guys"  is ... anti-climactic.  It's like a politician responding to "Why should people vote for you?" with "Well, I'm a candidate".

@StuartF I dunno. Pick up a person is not really pick up with a person.

There is the slang noun "a pick-up" based on the phrasal verb "to pick someone up" which are used to refer to the act of connecting with a stranger for  casual sex, and to such a stranger.  That is basically what the guy is hoping for, it seems, though maybe it's more open-ended.

They went to a local bar with a reputation for being a good place to pick up somebody for the night.
He | she was just a casual pick-up.

However, the phrasal verb "to pick up someone" is transitive, whereas the phrasal verb in the original context is "to pick up with someone", which is not an established verb, though it is similar in structure to "to take up with someone", which means to start being in their company on a regular basis, not, as here, just for the night or probably very short term if longer than one night.  So, via impromptu coinage by analogy, and colored by the slang-term "pick up", it means "to take up with someone -- but with the likelihood, if not the intention, that it will be short-term."
P.S. I put however in bold so that a certain person with a hair-trigger downvote reflex doesn't downvote this answer before reading to the end.
P.P.S. With regard to the definition in the Oxford Learners Dictionary, that dictionary goes too far in defining "pick up" as "to start again."  The editors are misled by the common context in which it is used ("We will pick up where we left off") but it is possible to "pick up a story" in medias res, somewhere after it has started, but we are not starting it "again"). It means to "join up with".  We join the story somewhere along its way in the same sense that we can pick up a trail, or another traveling group, when our paths cross.

Hi! I upvoted your good answer. I also upvoted another answer you wrote and someone downvoted it. Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!

American self-assuredness [eyes roll]. His gist is that she doesn't know what she's missing out on.
Pick up, hook up, or the British 'pull' are slang for desperate attempts to randomly connect, often manifest in the early hours of the morning as the club closes.
